# Which patch version to apply?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I'm currently applying patch SUPEE-6788 to a store that is running Magento CE 1.9.1.0 (it says so at the bottom of the admin panel).

When it comes to selecting the version for the patch, I'm a bit confused:

- Do I have to select "SUPEE-6788 for CE 1.9.1.0", as that is the latest update of Magento that I've installed?
- Do I have to select "SUPEE-6788 for CE 1.9.2.1", as I have already installed all previous patches, making my Magento installation identical to a 1.9.2.1 installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need SUPEE-6788 for CE 1.9.1.0, since that is the version that you are running.  The patch will address security issues only, there are other changes between 1.9.1.0 and 1.9.2.x.

Comment: Ah, great, so "SUPEE-6788 for CE 1.9.1.0" assumes that I have installed CE 1.9.1.0 and ALL patches leading up to SUPEE-6788? That's where I'm a bit confused.

Comment: yes, you'll want to install all security patches for 1.9.1.0 in the order that they were released

Answer (score 1):

Now that we have never understood with Magento, you have to login to their website/repository, find new release or patch, then you have to find out what version you are actually running right now, then download this patch, and when you will try to apply it you will get ton of errors, some of them are pretty stupid and obvious. 
There must be a shell/php script provided from magento that will do this all for you, all you have to enter is your MAG id, and downloads token:

thats why we have tried to create some automatic procedure:
https://gist.github.com/magenx/18669dfa81444bcf4ddf